# How to fire mouse event once for moving over child elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener, mouseover

When entering a DOM element, `mouseover` event will happen. Upon moving the mouse around the current element, no event happens, as `mouseover` is for entering.

However, this rule is not obeyed for child nodes. If moving the mouse over child nodes, the `mouseover` event will be triggered again and again, though no new event, as we are still in the original parent.

See this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ww645/). If we move the mouse over the parent (actually on its textNode), nothing new happens, but if we go to the child element (still on the parent), it will trigger the `mouseover` event again and again. In fact it will fire the mouse event every time mouse enters an elements (even inside the original parent element).

How we can make the `mouseover` only once for moving all over the parent (the original element in the `addEventListener`)? In the given example, I mean to avoid firing the event upon moving the mouse on the child element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in chrome and ff

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var e = event.fromElement || event.relatedTarget;
    if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date();
}, true);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3swb3/)

Reference: [Mouse Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html)

Answer (score 5):

What you really need is the [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) event, which does not bubble (unlike `mouseover`). From MDN:

> The synchronous mouseenter DOM event is dispatched when a mouse or
>   another pointing device enters the physical space given to the element
>   or one of its descendants.
>
> Similar to mouseover , it differs in that **it doesn't bubble** and that
>   it isn't sent when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants'
>   physical space to its own physical space.

Unfortunately, it's [not widely supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t017). One solution is to use jQuery (see [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)), which polyfills that event in all the browsers it supports. Another option is to check the element that triggered the event:

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "parent") { //Only execute following on parent mouseover
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date;
        this.childNodes[1].style.display="block";
    }
}, false);
```

Or [see here](http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/) for what looks at first glance to be a pretty good shim.

Comment: `mouseenter` event is for IE only, and I am talking about pure JS, not jQuery framework.

Comment: @Ali - `mouseenter` is actually in the spec, and is now supported in Firefox, IE and Opera. Hopefully, other browsers will catch up soon.

Comment: but it is still so soon to be used as a popular event, a majority of users (including me) use webkit browsers.

Comment: @Ali - Agreed, I too use a WebKit browser. I've updated my answer with a link to an article that seems to have a pretty good shim. I'd suggest giving that a try.

Answer (score 0):

in your example child element is not firing any event it is your parent element on which when you mouseover it runs your script and display result in your "time" div.

Comment: entering child element fires the event, as we have not left the parent.

Comment: @Ali but the script runs on id bases.