# Making psuedo element move upon hovering over its parent's parent tag

Tags: html, css, tags, pseudo-element

I want to make the border of my pseudo element move when the parent of its parent is hovered over. Basically I want it to move when I hover over **"lk"**, instead of only activating when hovering over **"ci"**, but I can't seem to get it to work. Does it only work with a div? If so, I'm open to this option. I've tried tried something similar with a div, but I still can't seem to get it to work, so I'm happy to learn how to do it.

HTML

```
<lk><de>Name:</de><ci>Luci`a Bloom</ci></lk>
```

CSS

```
lk{
margin-right:49px;
}

de{
color:black;
font-family:karla;
font-weight:900;
border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-right:7px;
}

ci{
color:black;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left:1px;
font-family:calibri;
border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA;
padding-bottom:5px;
font-weight:200;
position: relative;
font-size:15px;
color: black;
width: fit-content;
margin-left:1px
} 

ci:after { 
content: "";
border-bottom:1px solid black;
width: 100%;
height: 120%;
position: absolute;
top: -5px;
z-index: 1;
 right:0px;
 transition: 2.5s;   
 }

#deetz ci:hover:after{
border-bottom:1px solid black;
transition: 2.5s;
width:0%;
}
```

Comment: you can add an mouseOver event listener to the parent, and give it a callback that would grab the child element you want to manipulate, and do whatever you want to from there.

Comment: @HolyMoly what is that? and how do I insert it?

Comment: it's JavaScript, this is similar to what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202681/how-to-fire-mouse-event-once-for-moving-over-child-elements-in-javascript however you may need to tweak it to your need. If you do not know JS then maybe you can do it in css by nestling the child el's css inside the `:hover` of the parent. `parent:hover { child { border: pink} }` I have never tried that and have no idea if that approach would work, I am more a JS than Css person.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand your question more or less you want the psuedo hover to activate when hovered over lk element as a whole. If so try adding the hover psuedo class to the lk element and direct which element it needs to affect with the > selector

```
lk:hover > ci:after{
border-bottom:1px solid black;
transition: 2.5s;
width:0%;
}
```

Comment: @ScarlettLucĭa Sweet!